# Which stock of Gazprom to buy while investing from France?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, broker, international-trading

I would like to buy shares of Gazprom.

- I live in France
- My broker is Degiro

From the search I see two options

- Gazprom ADR SP./2 RL 5L 5 in Euro
- Gazprom Neft in LSE in USD
- OGZD in LSE and USD

Which one should I choose and why?

- One is going up and one other down, how is that possible?